# Tomcat cluster - how to verify node starvation?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, cluster, haproxy

We have a tomcat cluster with a load balancer (haproxy). As part of our upgrade script we would like to starve a single tomcat in the cluster of 3, wait until all the requests are handled for that particular tomcat. and only then we would like to shut it down and upgrade the web application running on that tomcat.

Our question is:

How can our script indicate if the tomcat is fully starved (all request have been taken cared of)?

Is there an API the tomcat itself exposes? or maybe we can query haproxy for that info?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is my haproxy configuration file:

```
global
debug
stats socket /etc/haproxy/haproxysock level admin

defaults
mode http
timeout connect 5s
timeout queue   300s
timeout client  300s
timeout server  300s


frontend http-in
bind *:8080
default_backend NG

backend NG
cookie JSESSIONID prefix
server 10.0.110.44 10.0.110.44:8080 cookie JSESSIONID_SERVER_1 check maxconn 500
server 10.0.110.45 10.0.110.45:8080 cookie JSESSIONID_SERVER_2 check maxconn 500
#server 10.0.110.41 10.0.110.41:8080 cookie JSESSIONID_SERVER_3 check maxconn 500
option httpclose
option forwardfor
balance roundrobin
option redispatch
retries 15


listen admin
bind *:8081
stats enable
stats refresh 1s
```

Comment: How is session persistence implemented in your `haproxy` configuration? You may wish to add the pertinent configuration details to your question.

Comment: Please see my EDIT

Answer (score 1):

Complete starvation is difficult to assert from the loadbalancer's point of view. There is really no telling wether there is a client still out there who has a `JSESSIONID` cookie that is prefixed for your `NOLB` server.

I can see at least two ways to go forward with this

1. estimate total starvation time based on your session lifetime

   - this is not perfect of course, since TTLs are getting renewed *during* the starvation phase
2. define a boundary (like 1 request per minute) to consider the server as starved

If Tomcat does have a way to enumerate valid sessions, that would allow for a safer way (via a servelet or similar).

Note that if you constrain yourself to stopping only fully starved appservers, a tenacious client can keep you from *ever* restarting.